# Запись аудио файла на сервер и в бд

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Есть скрипт записи звука с микрофона с помощью Recorder.js .
Вопрос заключается в следующем, как записанный звук можно сохранить на сервер и в бд записать ссылку на него с помощью php. Сам скрипт для превращения в blob :

```js
function createDownloadLink(blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    //add controls to the <audio> element 
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;
    //link the a element to the blob 
    link.href = url;
    link.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
    link.innerHTML = link.download;
    //add the new audio and a elements to the li element 
    li.appendChild(au);
    li.appendChild(link);
    //add the li element to the ordered list 
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: к FormData append свой blob и загружаете

Comment: В этом и проблема, не могли бы вы помочь с этим, я только на стадии обучения, а в гугле найти нужную информацию не получилось

Comment: через FormData отправляете blob файл на сервер и потом его сохраняете, как обычные файлы, которые пользователь присылает

Comment: Если не затруднит, не могли бы вы привести пример кода, с formdata до этого момента не сталкивалась